# Adding a class to an a element with a particular href using hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I'm trying to add an 'active' class to a particular element based on the URL hash but it's not working as I expect.

Here's my code:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
if(hash != false) {
    $('.products #copy div, #productNav li a').removeClass('active');
    $('.products #copy div#'+hash+'').addClass('active');
    $('#productNav li a[href*="'+hash+'"').addClass('active');
}
```

The second jQuery statement (the one that adds the 'active' class to the div) works as expected, but the third (the one that adds the 'active' class to the link) does not.

Anybody see anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks much
Marcus

Comment: Hi. Never mind - I have figured this out. I was missing my end ']'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind - I have figured this out. I was missing my end ']'.

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
if(hash != false) {
    $('.products #copy div, #productNav li a').removeClass('active');
    $('.products #copy div#'+hash+'').addClass('active');
    $('#productNav li a[href*="'+hash+'"]').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of the third line:

```
$('#productNav li a[href='+hash+']').addClass('active');
```